# Ubuntu 16.04: changing language on lock screen results in crash

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, lock-screen, input-language

When I change the language on lock screen with keyboard shortcut, the system freezes for a few seconds, the lock screen disappears (I haven't typed a password), for fraction of a second I see all my windows and then the lock screen appears again.

I can recreate this every time (on two clean Ubuntu installations with the latest updates), but it happens only if I use the keyboard shortcuts. Everything is fine if I change the language from the top menu.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: I logged this on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1605972

Comment: Turned out that there is already a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1598893

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04:  `Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  The problem started after latest `compiz` upgrade to `compiz:amd64 (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160714-0ubuntu1)`.  So we can try to downgrade it, but I didn't test it yet.

Comment: Answerers: If you wish to confirm the bug, then please go to the bug, register on Launchpad, and click the link for "Does this bug affect you?" to indicate you are impacted by the bug.  Note that this bug is marked as a duplicate of another bug.  **DO NOT** indicate whether you can or cannot confirm the bug here.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is now pushed to 16.04. With the latest updates everything is fine with me.